# QTextEdit how to clear the text when user typed in somethin Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm building gui for address ip and broadcast address calculator. And i have 3 objects in my mainwindow.ui - textEdit (you type your ip address into it), textEdit_2 (you type your subnet mask address into it), plainTextEdit (just a welcome box). This is my mainwindow.cpp.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

QString users_mask;
QString users_ip;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: #484848;");
    ui->textEdit->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid white; color: gray;");
    ui->textEdit->setPlainText("Enter ip address");
    ui->textEdit_2->setPlainText("Enter mask address here");
    ui->textEdit_2->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid white; color: gray;");
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText("Welcome to the ip address calculator!");
    ui->plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("border: 1px #484848; color: #FFFFFF;");
    ui->plainTextEdit->setEnabled(false);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::get(){

    users_ip = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    users_mask = ui->textEdit_2->toPlainText();
}

void MainWindow::on_calculate_clicked()
{
    get();
    qDebug()<<users_ip<<" -- "<<users_mask;
}
```

now i want the textEdit and textEdit_2 to be cleared whenever a user type something. and is there a function or smth that will allow doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `placeholderText` property, but you're using the wrong widget :) Use `QLineEdit` instead for those address inputs. `placeholderText` is the hint you want shown before user begins their input.

`QTextEdit` is a widget meant for general multi-line text editing, and what you're trying to do is a single-line input.

You should also give the widgets self-descriptive names. Instead of having to write *textEdit (you type your ip address into it)* you could just name that widget `ipAddress` and you wouldn't need to explain anything to anyone (much less yourself in a couple months of not looking at the code).

Comment: Thank you very very much!!!! That solved my problem :)))))